# AWS CDK or cloudformation to create ecs autoscaling with expression based metric spec

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, autoscaling

I have a situation where I want to use metric expression for target scaling of my ecs service. I understand that I need to specify the CustomizedMetricSpecification in TargetTrackingPolicy but I have not been able to find any documentation around it either in cdk or in cfn template directly. The documentations I have found only seem to point to specifying the basic metric spec with single metric with dimensions, metric name and spec.

I am currently specifying the metric through application autoscaling CLI like this. Unfortunately, doing it like this from cfn would require me write custom lambda which seems too much effort for something which should be simpler.

aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy 
--policy-name $POLICY_NAME 
--service-namespace ecs 
--resource-id service/$CLUSTER_NAME/$SERVICE_NAME 
--scalable-dimension ecs:service:DesiredCount 
--policy-type TargetTrackingScaling 
--target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration file://targetscaling.json

targetscaling.json contains the metric expression spec and the target value and scale in and scale out cooldown values.

Wanted to know if anyone has ever accomplished this ?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this might be only supported in CLI or SDK as of now - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/amazon-ec2-auto-scaling-supports-metric-math-target-tracking-policies/ Not sure if the same applies for ecs application autoscaling as well